# Ruby code to update model values in JSON

Tags: json, ruby

I can't find a way to merge these 2 lines in my ruby code:

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(options).merge ({ :id => self.id.upcase }) # upcase id
  super(options).reject { |k, v| v.nil? } # reject nil values
end
```

How to manage `merge` and `reject` in `super`?

EDIT: example of what super(options) returns:

> {"id"=>"6ea8db7f-18a8-422d-9510-5b615883ed7c", "user_id"=>1,
>   "contact_id"=>nil, "producer_id"=>nil }

The problem is when `contact_id` or `producer_id` are `nil`.

```
super(options).reject { |_k, v| v.nil? }.merge(id: id.upcase, contact_id: contact_id.upcase, producer_id: producer_id.upcase)
```

EDIT 2: this is working but it's very ugly

```
super(options).merge(id: id.upcase, contact_id: contact_id ? contact_id.upcase : nil, producer_id: producer_id ? producer_id.upcase : nil).reject { |_k, v| v.nil? }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain as many methods as you need to:

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(options).reject { |k, v| v.nil? }.merge ({ :id => self.id.upcase })
end
```

Here's somewhat more conventional version of your code:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(options).reject { |_k, v| v.nil? }.merge(id: id.upcase)
end
```

- use spaces while setting default value of an argument
- `_k` means that `k` is not used in the block
- no need for `{}` in the `merge`
- no need for `self`

Comment: Thanks Andrey! And your second code is nice and well explained. Works like a charm.

Comment: why did you choose `_k` and not just `_`? Generally I see this written as `reject { |_,v| ...}`

Comment: @engineersmnky I assume it's a matter of taste. In this particular (simple) case both would work equally fine for me, but when dealing with more complex/meaningful hashes, I call my block variables with full name, and for unused ones i use `_variable`, rather then `_` because it helps me to read and remember the code faster in the future :)

Comment: Sorry, but if `id` is nil, `upcase` won't work of course. Does `reject` should not remove `id` if it's `nil` before trying upcase ? I got `NoMethodError (undefined method upcase for nil:NilClass)` if id is `nil` (or if another field is `nil` and set to `upcase`).

Comment: @alex.bour i cant tell before seeing what `super(options)` returns. But if it returns hash, it indeed should remove it.

Comment: I added an EDIT: note that the problem is with `contact_id` or `producer_id` (`id` is of course never `nil`).

Comment: @alex.bour it should work. Ill be near laptop in ~1h and double check.

Comment: @alex.bour `a.reject {|k,v| v.nil?}
=> {"id"=>"6ea8db7f-18a8-422d-9510-5b615883ed7c", "user_id"=>1}` So reject part is working.

Comment: Yes, reject part is working. Problem was with fields that can be nil and to apply upcase on them. Please, look at my EDIT 2. It's working but code is very dirty. :-)

Comment: @alex.bour `super(options)
  .merge(id: id.upcase, contact_id: contact_id&.upcase, producer_id: producer_id&.upcase)
  .reject { |_k, v| v.nil? }` a bit cleaner :) It uses safe navigation operator `&.` (if you're on Ruby >= 2.3)

Comment: Using ruby 2.2 currently. I will install 2.3. Thanks Andrey.

Comment: @alex.bour If you are not bounded by specific Ruby version due to whatever reasons, I'd suggest always keep it the latest. Currently it's 4.2.1 :)

Comment: In fact, it's 2.4.1 ;-) Thanks for all your help.